# When do sieges start?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have been playing for about two in-game years now and still no sieges. I am kind of relieved, but also worried one might happen soon.

I read on the forums that sieges start happening when there's a mayor, but I can't find any information on the wiki. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goblin sieges happen when you have goblins on your map and you have met certain conditions.

These conditions include

- Number of dwarves
- Amount of things traded

How you've dealt with other goblin invaders earlier also effects the timing of the siege.  If goblin ambushes were allowed to get a lot of kills the siege may come earlier.

If you haven't seen goblin snatchers or goblin ambushes yet, you probably don't have goblins around to siege.  If you want one you should anger the elves or humans.

Comment: Could you expand on "How you've dealt with other goblin invaders"?

Comment: Does that mean that if there are no goblins on my map (not in my civ list) that there will not be any sieges unless I anger elves or humans? Neat.

Comment: @Arda Yes it does mean that.

Answer (score 0):

In the old version at least, you needed 80 dwarfs for sieges to start showing up. Having a hostile civilization around also helps :-)